# Importing one xsd in to Another

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  targetNamespace="http://redbus.in/ travels /types" 
  xmlns:rbt="http://redbus.in/ travels /types">

<xs:import namespace="http:kesineni.com/reservation/details" 
  schemaLocation="Kesineni.xsd"/>

<xs:element name="redbus"  type="rbt:redbustype"/> 
    <xs:complexType name="redbustype">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="passengerinfo" 
              type="rbt:passengerinfotype"/>
            <xs:element name="reservationinfo" 
              type="rbt:reservationinfotype"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="passengerinfotype">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="identity" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="age" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="reservationinfotype">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any></xs:any>
        </xs:sequence>

    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This is my first xsd in which reservationinfo is of any type, which means it will support reservation from any vendor. My problem is that I am importing `Kesineni.xsd` and I am getting a problem. Tt is asking which one will be root. I want redbus to be root.

2nd xsd (Kesineni.xsd) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:kst="http:kesineni.com/reservation/details" 
  targetNamespace="http:kesineni.com/reservation/details">
    <xs:element name="keseneniticket" type="kst:kesenenitype"/>
    <xs:complexType name="kesenenitype">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tktno" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="serviceno" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You say "i am getting some problem it is asking which one will be root". Please tell us what "it" is (what software are you running and how are you running it), and please quote the actual error message rather than a paraphrase.

Comment: If you want `redbus` to be root then `keseneniticket` will be a child of `redbus`. Either place it in the right position or post some xml sample so we can place it for you.